# why am i getting error massage of, "NO USABLE PYTHON FOUND" when python 3.8 is already installed

Tags: python

When writing the below code in Ubuntu Terminal

```
./setup.sh --install
```

I am getting the below error message

```
No Usable python found. Please make sure to have python 3.6 or python 3.7 installed.
```

However, Python 3.8 is already installed in the system.

Comment: you'll have to show us `setup.sh` ...

Comment: Well, Python 3.8 is no "python 3.6 or python 3.7".

Comment: @OrenIshShalom-Can you please elaborate

Comment: @KlausD. Isn't a higher version of python supposed to work with the lover version as well?

Comment: I mean show us what's inside `setup.sh`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.